# How to use stsadm export avoiding to export the user names

Tags: sharepoint, export, stsadm

I want to export a site with "stsadm export" in order to import on an other server

My structure is good but it imports all the user names and I don't want these users

Can anyone tell me how to do to keep my security groups without the users??

thanks in advance

Sam

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the [SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/) hosted at CodePlex.com.
It has the ability to exclude user accounts, but include groups.